# How many non isomorphic semidirect products are there between $\mathbb Z_2$ and $SL(2,3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I know that $GL(2,3)$ is one of this, but i need the characterization of all possibles of the semidirect products between $\mathbb Z_2$ and $SL(2,3)$.

Thanks, for any help.

Comment: Something is wrong here, it is ${\rm GL}(2,3)$ that is a semidirect product of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ (the normal subgroup) with $C_2$. (Also when you refer to a semidirect product of $A$ and $B$ you need to make it clear which of $A$ and $B$ is the normal subgroup.)

Comment: Can you write some of your ideas?

Comment: Iknow that the $Aut(SL(2,3)\cong S_4$,and I know its subgroups of order 2 subgroup of order of which I know only two of these are non-conjugated (this clear by looking at the corresponding Claes conjugate classes), then I know I have at most two semidirect products I need, but not idetificar if they are isomorphic or not and if not, classify that is different from $GL(2,3).$

Comment: @katie, look my stuff until now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: now you know there are only two possibly non-isomporphic semidirect products, namely $$\textrm{GL}(2,3)$$ and $$\mathbb{Z}_2\times \textrm{SL}(2,3).$$  Show that they are not isomorphic because their corresponding centers have different cardinality.